# When using C# XmlSchemaInference to create an XML schema, how to relax the <xs:sequence> option?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a piece of code which is trying to check that an XML fragment satisfies an XSD schema.  So for instance, whether the XML fragment:

```
<A>
  <C />
</A>
```

When compared with a schema based on the full XML of:

```
<A>
  <B />  <!-- optional -->
  <C />  <!-- optional -->
  <D />  <!-- optional -->
</A>
```

Would be 100% valid.

I've used the XmlSchemaInference in C# to infer the schema from the full XML, and it creates:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="B">...</xs:element>
        <xs:element name="C">...</xs:element>
        <xs:element name="D">...</xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The trouble is is that the XmlSchemaInference has decided that the children of "A" should be an xs:sequence - so it expects all of the nodes to be there in the correct order.  XmlSchemaInference seems to have surprisingly few options (one - and that is only for the type) - is there a way of persuading it to only check that the node is one of the valid options, and not to enforce the sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not use

```
schema.Occurrence = XmlSchemaInference.InferenceOption.Relaxed;
```

?

And redefine XML as

```
<A>
  <B />  <!-- optional -->
  <C />  <!-- optional -->
  <D />  <!-- optional -->
  <C />  <!-- optional -->
  <B />  <!-- optional -->
</A>
```

to avoid the ordering issue?

Comment: *Groan* - I spotted the TypeInference option, but not the Occurrence one, for some reason.  Thanks, @spodger.

Comment: :-) @MikeSadler we all have our groan moments!

Comment: Actually, there's still a problem - it now doesn't mind if some elements are missing, but it *does* mind if the ones there are in the wrong order.

Comment: Can you redefine your xml? I've added it to the answer as I don't appear to be able to format here.

Comment: The schema's inferred from a large XML, so I don't have much control over it :-(

Comment: Just checking I understand this. You have no control over the XML but you have a sample from which you are generating a schema. Can you not edit that schema to suit the variability of the XML?

Comment: It's all done within a process, so the schema is never actually written to disk.  I'd hoped that this would be a quick, elegant solution, but it's looking as though I'm going to need to approach the problem from another direction...

Comment: So, do you infer a schema from an initial XML document and then validate further documents against that schema on the fly?

Comment: That's right, although I'm actually checking the syntax of dozens of XSLT templates (by converting them into dummy XML files, then comparing them to the template).  However, I've just re-written it to just work out the XPath expression for the XSLT "select" clause, and then just do a SelectSingleNodes on the sample document to check that it's valid.  It's a lot simpler, and it's all under my control.

Comment: Fair enough. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @spodger, and thanks for the help.  I'm sure I'll end up using schemas again at some point, so it's not wasted knowledge.